What does Hint: Bring text file back from the dead with C-y mean in Midnight Commander?
I have recently install midnight commander and while viewing git repository I just cloned, I saw this Hint: Bring text file back from the dead with C-y
I've searched on Google to no avail.
Could you tell me please, what it means?

what happens when you use that command?

It’s the “yank” command that pastes in whatever has been killed (the contents of the “kill buffer”). It’s more verbosely described in the ordinary manual. I don’t know whether this is worthy of turning into a proper answer with references etc., but anyone is free to take it and run.

C-y is emacs-speak for Ctrl-y or Control-y (hold the Control/Ctrl key and press the y key).  I'm a little surprised the Midnight Commander docs don't have a description of how the various command keystrokes are printed in the documentation.  If MC tends to use emacs-style keystrokes, it's reasonable for them to assume "C-y" would be recognized, but if it uses vi-style keystrokes then the docs ought to use vi-speak for them in the docs.

Is the question about what C-y means or about what the rest of the text means? Did you find any of the other “hints” similarly confusing or was it only this one that was unclear?

@SottoVoce If it was vi-speak, then “yank” would copy, not paste.

@Kusalananda my reference to "emacs-speak" is the rendering of the keystroke as "C-y", not the function the program performs when the keystroke is pressed.

@SottoVoce I’m aware. I’m just saying that  it’s more likely that the software uses Emacs-inspired conventions than Vi-inspired ones. … as a response to your “ If MC tends to use emacs-style keystrokes […]”

@SottoVoce Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know C-y meant Ctrl-y (haven't see that before)

@PetrL. You're welcome.  The documentation for the GNU Emacs editor uses that style of abbreviation for Control and Alt (Meta) keystrokes.  It's visible everywhere in the GNU Emacs Reference Card (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf).  The text under "Key Binding Notation" gives the details.  This is why I called the abbreviation "emacs-speak" in my previous comment.
